# how to use jquery loop function to target many element with different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, loops

Currently, I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // #filtertab-00 replace this with your element id
    $('#filtertab-00 .box-content .es-nav .elastislide-next, #filtertab-00 .box-content     .es-nav .elastislide-prev').click(function() {
    // trigger lazy load
    $("#filtertab-00 img.lazy").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(150*i).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("data-original");
            $(this).attr('src',src);
        });
    });
});
```

});

and i want to use this function to target object names (id) as below:

```
filtertab-00
filtertab-10
filtertab-20
filtertab-30
filtertab-40
filtertab-50
filtertab-60
....
filtertab-90
```

Does anyone know how to use the loop function to get it work?

i just want this:
**when i click pre or next button after i select a tab(name varies from filtertab-00 to filtertab-90),it will activate lazyloading for images at current selected tab.**

any idea is welcome!

Comment: Can you give them all a common CSS class that works as a selector? That would be easier.

Comment: "Will this work?" - well, to answer that question I'd have to run it. Given you can do this as easily you shouldn't need to ask us if something works. You can run it and tell us why it doesn't work (error message, incorrect results, etc.) or if it does work then no need to even ask a question...

Comment: it has common css class ,but the class is used by others too.it is not independent.how to make it work?

Comment: ok,thanks Chris.i will be back in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [jQuery's attribute-starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). You can then just select all IDs that begin with `filtertab-` using jQuery like this:

```
$('div[id^="filtertab-"]').each( //magic goes here );
```

Note: This method is slow because it has to search the DOM for elements with IDs that meet the criteria, but it does the job. I've never noticed an appreciable latency.

Comment: but if i do so ,i click the '>' '<',then it will activate all the images for lazyloading instead of lazyloading the images at the current tab.

Comment: i click pre or next button when i select a tab(name varies from filtertab-00 to filtertab-90),it will activate lazyloading for images at current selected tab.

Comment: I'll try looking at the source code on your jsBuying site, but I'm having some difficulty actually identifying the issue. I'll update if I find anything helpful.

Comment: @user3571443 From what I can see, the problem is that the images are already loaded when you use the < or > arrows because Lazy Load is dependent on scroll height. You would need to find a way to leave off the .lazy class from the images __until they are visible in the browser__, which is another issue entirely. Alternatively, I'm guessing that you purchased this [BossModule](http://demo.bossthemes.com/bossmodules2/) for the carousel, so could instead modify that script instead to create a fadeIn effect.

Comment: i enable the code at the bottom to make sure that:when i scroll down ,images at carousels will load automatically.but as a matter of fact ,as you mentioned,lazyload is dependent on scroll height,and what is more ,it only load the images at the view port,images at first tab(after enable ski_invisible) will not load after clicking < or >.that's why i want to use code which can detect click event and load the images at current selected tab.

Comment: i have checked the script,it use tpl to generate the carousel modules,please tell me your email if any modification is needed.

Comment: if i remove the class ,then all the images will not load when i scroll down,and only after i click then images load,it seems before i click i see no images.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved through selector magic as filoxo described but since you want the images, here's another version involving `find()` to get your actual images.

```
$('div[id^="filtertab-"]').find("img.lazy").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(150*i).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("data-original");
    $(this).attr('src',src);
  });
});
```

In addition to that, check out [the impressive list of jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). They cover a lot of ground :)

Comment: Sorry, had one to many closing brackets in there. It should work now.

Comment: hi,yes,console reports no problem,but lazyload got a problem now.it will not show the products normally at first tab in carousel(homefilter),i really have nothing to do now:(

Comment: the code uses to activate lazyload after click '<' or '>' ,it seems that it doesnt work at this sense.